# WhatsApp Status Save In Android 11 or above model and adopter issues

Tags: java, android, whatsapp, android-11, android-12

I am getting issue with loading status from specified path .statuses provide me model and adopter that i can see my data loaded into recyclerview

```
Intent intent;
StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
File statusDir = whatsFolder;
String str = "android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT \>= 29) {
intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();
String scheme = ((Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(str)).toString().replace("/root/", "/document/");
String stringBuilder = scheme +
"%3A" +
statusDir;
intent.putExtra(str, Uri.parse(stringBuilder));

        } else {

//                intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE");
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.putExtra(str, Uri.parse(statusDir.toString()));
}

   
        startActivityForResult(intent, 12345);
```

//intent code ended

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE){
            Uri uriTree = data.getData();
            Log.d(TAG, "WalkTree: " + uriTree.toString() );
    
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uriTree, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("uri", String.valueOf(uriTree));
            editor.apply();
            gotoNext();
    
            Toast.makeText(this, "FilePath:"+uriTree, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            WalkTree( uriTree );
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
```

//onresult Ended

// for this below code I need model and adopter

```
private void WalkTree( Uri uriTop ) {

        Log.d( TAG, "LoadFileList: " + uriTop.toString() );
    
        DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uriTop);
        DocumentFile files[]      = documentFile.listFiles();
    
        if( files == null ) {
            Log.d( TAG, "files is null in LoadFileList()" );
        } else {
            for( DocumentFile f : files ) {
    
                if( f.isDirectory() ) {
    
                    Log.d( TAG, "FOLDER: " + f.getName());
    
                    if( f.getName().toLowerCase().contains("lost.dir") ) {
                        Log.d( TAG, "IGNORE LOST.DIR");
                    } else {
                        // Recurse into the folder..
                        WalkTree( f.getUri() );
                    }
    
                } else {
                    Log.d( TAG, "FILE: " + f.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

// This how i load my data to recycler view which is not loading

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT \>= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("app", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String uri = sharedPreferences.getString("uri","no");
            Log.e("FilePath",uri);
            DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getContext(), Uri.parse(uri));
            Log.e("FilePath document ",documentFile.getName());
    
            File file = new File(uri);
    
            f = new ArrayList<>();
    
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                File[] listFile = file.listFiles();
                if (listFile != null) {
                    Arrays.sort(listFile, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                        if (!listFile[i].getAbsolutePath().contains(".nomedia"))
                            f.add(new StatusModel(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                    }
                }
            }
    
    
    
        }
```

// adopter code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -\> {
myAdapter = new RecentAdapter(Whatsapp_Fragment.this, f, Whatsapp_Fragment.this);
imageGrid.setAdapter(myAdapter);
loaderLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (f == null || f.size() == 0) {
                    emptyLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    emptyLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 1000);
```

/* I tried to get specific folder I got .Statuses folder path like this

content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses

But now I don't see my statuses.*/

Comment: `I am getting issue with loading status from specified path .statuses provide me model and adopter that i can see my data loaded into recyclerview` ? Sorry, what did you say? Please reformulate as i have no idea what this is about.

Comment: My app is not loading statuses this my code.

Comment: If you do not take any effort to explain your problem the why should we do any effort?

Comment: Thank you blackapps i have got solution. I will share link to the repository soon.